# How can $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$ exist even when $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ does not?

Tags: calculus

My book says that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$ may exist even when $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ may not.

I don't understand how that is. Doesn't $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$ mean we first differentiate $f$ with respect to x, and if the partial derivative exists, we differentiate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ with respect to $y$?

Comment: You can check $f(x,y) = xy + x^2 \chi(x)$ (where $\chi(x)$ is Dirichlet function) as an example. As you were told in the comments, differentiating order should be read from right to left in case it matters.

Answer (score 6):

You're reading the notation backwards. We write differential operators as being applied on the left. We build this fact into our simplified notation by saying that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}$ is meant to be understood as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.

Once you recognize that, it is easy to build counterexamples; mookid's is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** consider a function that has no derivative, $g(x)$.
Then define $f(x,y) = g(x)$.

Comment: Did you read the body of the question?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I did. But the explanation of Ian is very fine.